# Run rake script for specific time range

Tags: ruby, rake

i need to run rake script for specific time. For example 10 minutes, 1 hour, etc., and if the script it's not finished stop it anyway.

Why i need this ? Because after some hours the memory is full!

Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you check in the script itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should first consider what is making this script use up so much memory.

(one thing would be loading up lots of records from the database, and appending them to an array)

But assuming you have already done everything you can,
I'd do something like this.

```
LIVE_FOR = 1.hour

def run!
  finish_before = LIVE_FOR.from_now

  array = get_the_array # some big collection to operate on

  array.each do |object|
    while Time.now < finish_before
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

But really, i'd first try to tackle why you have a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks matthew, the memory problem it's because the task works with thousend of active records!

Comment: that shouldn't be a problem though. Have you tried doing a `Model.find_each`, this will load them up in batches of 1000, allowing them to be garbage collected. I suggest create another question so we can help make this script better.